# SQL Native client driver 10 vs 11

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012, sql-server-native-client

Has anyone experienced a difference between SQL driver SQLNCLI11.1 vs 10.1?

I inherited a complex SSIS package where I had to make minor changes (package loads data from 18 files to a SQL database).

The package works well with 10.1. But gives an error with Unicode to non-Unicode conversion with 11.1. I didn't want to change the mappings in the whole SSIS package for my change. So I'm planning to use 10.1 provider explicitly in the connection string.

Do any of you see any issue with this approach?

Answer (score 1):

Only the sql server native client 11 can connect to SQL Server 2016.
SQL server native client 10.1 cannot connect to SQL Server 2016.

You can download sql server native client 11 here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50402

Comment: I may be missing something. Help me understand how it is relevant to the question.

Comment: Sorry. My statement just answer your first part of the question. I have no idea about the character conversion.

Comment: Thanks. That clarifies

Comment: What if comparability mode on the SQL 2016 instance is set to support 2014?